# What does "open the ball" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> “Your partners for the Yule Ball, Potter,” she said coldly. “Your dance partners.”
>
> Harry's insides seemed to curl up and shrivel.
>
> “Dance partners?” He felt himself going red. “I don't dance,” he said
>   quickly.
>
> “Oh yes, you do,” said Professor McGonagall irritably. “That's what
>   I'm telling you. Traditionally, the champions and their partners **open
>   the ball**.”
>
> Harry had a sudden mental image of himself in a top hat and tails,
>   accompanied by a girl in the sort of frilly dress Aunt Petunia always
>   wore to Uncle Vernon's work parties.
>
> “I'm not dancing,” he said. ...

I got the definition for "*open the ball*" from dictionaries:  *To open the ball to begin the dancing, to begin operations*. But I feel "begin the dancing" doesn't sound quite exactly what it means in this context. What does it suppose to mean here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right that "open the ball" [means](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/open_the_ball) "begin the dancing" or "start of dancing at a ball."

Professor McGonagall is asking Harry about his dance partner. I assume Harry is a champion and by tradition, "champions and their partners" should start the dancing at a ball. Presumably, the other competitors can join in after they start their dance.

Since he does not dance and does not have a dancing partner, he replied, "I don't dance" and "I'm not dancing".

Comment: I don't quite get "start the dancing" here. Is it "champions and their partners" dance first and the rest follow at the ball?

Comment: @dan Yep, it means the "champions and their partners" kick off the dancing while I assume the others could simply join after they start.

Comment: Does "open the ball" mean the same as "open the dancing"?

Comment: @dan Yep, but it usually refers to dancing at a ball.

Comment: @dan You're welcome!

Comment: It sounds to me that this use of 'open' is like 'lead'. Can we say "lead the dancing"?

Comment: @dan It's more of like "start the dancing", since "lead the dancing" has the meaning that everyone follows the leader's dancing moves; the idea is more or less there. The champions will start dancing first and the others gradually start dancing later.

Comment: I would include "begin" and "commence" as alternatives as well, in addition to "start".

Comment: Yep, I agree that they're suitable alternatives ^ @dan